# yarn install failed on my JHipster application after create an entity called post

Tags: jhipster

I have creating an entity called post using the command `jhipster entity post` after in some time I need to run `yarn install` to check some package update. When I run `yarn install` I got an error as follow

```
$ ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json 
Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve ng-jhipster relative to /home/nifras/Desktop/hire.it.nearby/src/main/webapp/app/shared/shared-libs.module.ts., resolving symbol HireitnearbySharedLibsModule in /home/nifras/Desktop/hire.it.nearby/src/main/webapp/app/shared/shared-libs.module.ts, resolving symbol HireitnearbySharedLibsModule in /home/nifras/Desktop/hire.it.nearby/src/main/webapp/app/shared/shared-libs.module.ts, resolving symbol HireitnearbySharedLibsModule in /home/nifras/Desktop/hire.it.nearby/src/main/webapp/app/shared/shared-libs.module.ts
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
nifras@nifras:~/Desktop/hire.it.nearby$
```

why does it happen? How do I recover from this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does it work if you use `yo jhipster:entity` instead?

Comment: yes, it is work for `yo jhipster:entity` command after `yarn upgrade` what is the different between `jhipster entity` and `yo jhipster:entity`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `yo jhipster[:XXX]` instead of `jhipster[ XXX]`, as JHipster CLI is in beta, and doesn't behave exactly as the old yeoman way. The reason here is, that we do some npm module management, like saving a copy of currently used JHipster to node_modules to ensure you will still use the same version for future commands.

In general, `jhipster` commands should behave the same way was `yo jhipster`, but as it is recently released, there are several issues still unsolved, yet.

If you find a way of reconstructing the issue, feel free to send an issue to our [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues)